# How to get Facebook login working without using standard button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get it so that, when users click a "submit" button on my site, Facebook checks to see if the user is authenticated, and if not, launches a popup prompting them to authenticate (rather than putting the standard Facebook button on the site).

It works fine when I follow the tutorial exactly, but when I tried to modify it to work when my button is clicked (rather than the standard one), it stopped working. No error messages, the page just doesn't notice any of the Javascript --- none of the `console.log`s are even showing up. Thanks for taking a look. Here's the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Vote</title>
<link href="https://istrauss6.neocities.org/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '1560520617436290',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v5.0'
    });
  };
</script>
<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>

<!--{% extends "boring.html"%}-->

<!--{% block title %} Vote {% endblock %}-->

<!--{% block main %}-->


<form action = "/insert_vote" method = "post" onsubmit="">
    <div action = "/insert_vote" method = "post" onsubmit="">
        <div class="smalltext">
            {% for dict_item in vote_choices %}
                <input type="radio" name="options" padding="10px" margin="10px" id="{{ dict_item['id'] }}"
                value="{{ dict_item['id'] }}"> {{ dict_item['choice'] }} </input><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // The user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token
    // and signed request each expire.
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // The user hasn't authorized your application.  They
    // must click the Login button, or you must call FB.login
    // in response to a user gesture, to launch a login dialog.
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
             console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
             FB.api('/me', function(response) {
               console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
             });
            } else {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        });
        }
 });
 }
</script>

    </div>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are most likely simply running into the popup blocker here … You are calling `FB.login` in the callback of the asynchronous `FB.getLoginStatus`, so the browser sees no direct connection between the user clicking the button, and trying to open the popup, any more - and so it blocks the popup, because it appears to be “unsolicited”. Either check the login status before the button gets clicked, or call `FB.login` directly - if the user already authorized your app, the popup will just close itself again immediately anyway.

Comment: I tried switching it so the <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button> is at the end, rather than the beginning, but same results

Comment: The position in the DOM (or the script?) doesn’t have anything to do with whether popups get blocked or not. You need to call `FB.login` _directly_ in the click handler, wrapping it into anything else asynchronous will get it blocked.